# In Photoshop - how to Export As webP format in different scales

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, html, scale, webp

Until today, when I wanted to export image in few scales I would:

File -> Export -> Export As -> then add the sizes I want and select the format (png, jpg, etc..) and click Export All

Now I am starting to work with **webP** files format,
I have added the plugin to photoshop to be able to save files in webP format,
But now,

How can I do the same and **export the same image in few scales in webP format**?

Answer (score 1):

Export the images as PNG as you would normally, using *Export As*. Then record an Action to open and export one of the PNG images as WebP.  Apply the Action to all the images in a folder using *File > Automate > Batch*.